# How to fetch pivot data in php from mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

i have an sql query like this

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = GETDATE()
DECLARE @VJ datetime = DATEADD(DAY, DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date), DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww,0,DATEADD(YEAR,-1, @Date)), 0)-1)

SELECT 'Printed:', [7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20]
FROM (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, prWhen) prHour,
             COUNT(VID) CountPr
      FROM myDBO
      WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), prWhen, 104)=CONVERT(varchar(10), @Date,104)
      GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,prWhen)) as SRC
PIVOT (AVG(CountPz)
       FOR prHour IN ([7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20])) as pvt
```

and the result of this query is this:
[image]

I'm checking every hour how many sheets were printed. The query is working. But now i would like to make a chart(chart.js) with this data. First i created a php file:

```
<?php  
        $serverName = "....";
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"...", "Uid" => "...", "PWD" => 
        "....");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

            $sql="...."; //copied the query from above
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
            echo $row['pvt'];   

        ?>
```

And here is my problem how get i get the pvt row.
The command `echo $row['pvt'];` is not working. I'm getting a notice

> Notice: Undefined index: pvt

how can i extract this to an array ? key:value => 7:71

Comment: try to debug and check the value of `$row` ie `print_r($row);`

Comment: Array ( [0] => Printed: [] => Printed: [1] => 71 [7] => 71 [8] => 175 [9] => 58 [10] => 82 [11] => 69 [12] => [13] => [14] => [15] => [16] => [17] => [18] => [19] => [20] => ) thx i got it